# node server caching files, not changing anything until close and reopen terminal and server

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting same error  until the terminal closed  and reopen,  even after i update my code (logs). Server is caching files. I am using ***nodemon*** .

- How to run server without caching files.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon only monitors for the changes only for the current working directory. So please make sure you are running/starting nodemon at the proper location.
Or you can manually add the --watch parameter for desired directories or files in your script line, like:

nodemon --watch app --watch libs app/server.js

Well, I have also used this in multiple applications but didn't get any such caching issue.

Thanks